# StreamingResponseBody heap usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i have got simple method in controller which streams content from database, streaming works as intended, download starts right after calling endpoint. Problem is heap usage, streaming 256 MB file takes 1GB heap space. If I would replace `service.writeContentToStream(param1, param2, out)` with method that reads data from local file to input stream and copying to passed output stream result is same. Biggest file I can stream is 256 MB. Is there possible solution to overcome heap size limit?

```
    @GetMapping("/{param1}/download-stream")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadAsStream(
            @PathVariable("param1") String param1,
            @RequestParam(value = "param2") String param2
    ) {
        Metadata metadata = service.getMetadata(param1);
        StreamingResponseBody stream = out ->  service.writeContentToStream(param1, param2, out);
           return ResponseEntity.ok()             
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;" + getFileNamePart() + metadata.getFileName())
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(metadata.getFileSize()))
                .body(stream);
    }
```

`service.writeContentToStream` method

```
 try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
     StreamUtils.copy(fis, dataOutputStream);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     log.error("Error writing file to stream",e);
 }
```

Matadata class contains only information about filesize and filename, there is no content stored there

**EDIT**
implementation of StreamUtils.copy() method, it comes from spring library
[StreamUtils.copy()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StreamUtils.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream-). Buffer size is set to 4096. Setting buffer to smaller size does not allow me to download bigger files

```
    /**
     * Copy the contents of the given InputStream to the given OutputStream.
     * Leaves both streams open when done.
     * @param in the InputStream to copy from
     * @param out the OutputStream to copy to
     * @return the number of bytes copied
     * @throws IOException in case of I/O errors
     */
    public static int copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        Assert.notNull(in, "No InputStream specified");
        Assert.notNull(out, "No OutputStream specified");

        int byteCount = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            byteCount += bytesRead;
        }
        out.flush();
        return byteCount;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the JVM heap with -Xmx flag?

Comment: the point is im limited to 1GB heap size by client. I need to work with files 500MB+ which currently leds to heap space error

Comment: What is your service doing? I have a hunch you are first reading everything into memory and than start to stream instead of stream directly. Also what is that `Metadata` class, does it really only contain metadata or also the file content?

Comment: metadata class contains only filesize and filename, added relevant part of service method in orginal question. dataOutputStream is passed to this method from controller method

Comment: Have you configured a/the TaskExecutor (as *"highly recommended"* by javadoc)? Is webflux on board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was logging dependency, so if you are having problems with identifying the cause of heap usage, take a look at your logging configuration:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an [article](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/asynchronous-streaming-request.html) back in 2016 regarding `StreamingResponseBody` when it was first released. You can read that to get more of an idea. But even without that what you are trying to do with the following code is not scalable at all (Imagine 100 users concurrently trying to download).

```
 try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
     StreamUtils.copy(fis, dataOutputStream);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     log.error("Error writing file to stream",e);
 }
```

The above code is very memory intensive and nodes with high memory can only work with this and you always will have an upper bound on the file size (Can it download a 1TB file in 5 years?)

What you should do is the following;

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = fis.read(data)) > 0) {
        dataOutputStream.write(data, 0, read);
    }
    dataOutputStream.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Error writing file to stream",e);
}
```

This way your code can download files of any size given that the user is able to wait and will not require a lot of memory

Comment: Hey, added implementation of StreamUtils.copy(fis, dataOutputStream). It is same as solution proposed by you. Smaller buffer size does not work either. Can you please explain why my solution is memory intesive?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

0. Run the server inside the Java profiler. For example [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) (it costs money).
1. Try `ServletResponse.setBufferSize(...)`
2. Check, if you have some filters configured in the application.
3. Check the output buffer of the application server. In case of the Tomcat it could be quite tricky. It has a long list of possible buffers:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html